# If a cookie doesn't exist, fancy should be appear

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I would like to display '.fancybox' if cookies don't exist but I'm not sure how to proceed.

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if( $.cookie('query') != 1 ) { 


  jQuery(document).ready(function() 


    {
        $.fancybox(
        '<h2>Hi!</h2><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam quis mi eu elit tempor facilisis id et neque</p>',
        {
                'autoDimensions'    : false,
            'width'                 : 350,
            'height'                : 'auto',
            'transitionIn'      : 'none',
            'transitionOut'     : 'none'
        }
      );
  });

  $.cookie( 'query', '1',  { expires: 7, path: '/' } );
}

</script>
```

Comment: Welcome to [SO], please read the [faq].

Comment: If you could set up your problem in jsfiddle.net, that would help also.

Answer (score 1):

Put your if statement inside the document.ready call. That should get it working.

Comment: I still cant get it, could you @aaronfrost take a look?